# "No such table" error while loading the .db file in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I'm trying to read the .db file in python code, whereas i getting "no table found an" error. But i could see the table when I import it onto MYSQL DB.

```
import sqlite3;
import pandas as pd;

con=None

def getConnection():
    databaseFile="test.db"
    global con
    if con == None:
        con=sqlite3.connect(databaseFile)
    return con


def queryExec():
    con=getConnection()
    result=pd.read_sql_query("select * from Movie;",con)
    result


queryExec()
```

Even I tried using the absolute path of the .db file, but no luck.

Comment: sqlite of mysql ???

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're trying to read data from **SQLite** database file, here is a simpler way to do it.

```
import sqlite3

import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")

with con:
    df = pd.read_sql("select * from Movie", con)

print(df)
```